# Jquery .filter() Question

Tags: jquery, filter

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<span class="child">10</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<span class="child">20</span>
</div>
```

I want to filter and hide parent div based on it's span value (child value), so have thought of doing something like:

```
<script>
$('span.child').filter(function(index) {
 return ($(this).text() < '15');
}).$(this).parent().hide();
</script>
```

No success... I am not hiding Parent div based on Span Value..

Anyone can help me ?

Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery('span.child').filter(function(index) {
   return (jQuery(this).text() < '15');  
}).parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove that last `$(this)`, like this:

```
$('span.child').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).text() < '15';
}).parent().hide();
```

`.filter()` returns the filtered set of elements, it takes what you selected, filters out what you wanted gone, then you just keep chaining the result.  [You can see this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/bmrdk/).